# Understanding jQuery $(this).closest( element );

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I would just like to know what `$(this)` refers to when you use it within a function called by a button.

Is it referring to the button element or is it referring to the function itself.

Code example:

```
<div>
<span class="fileError"></span>
<input type="file" class="understanding" />
</div>

<script>
$('.understanding').click(function(){

   $(this).closest('div').find('span.fileError').html('My brain needs help');
});
</script>
```

Things I have tried to change the html of my span

`$(this).prev('span.fileError').html();`

`$(this).closest('div').find('span.fileError').html();`

`$(this).closest('div').find('span.fileError').text();`

Links I have tried:

[Jquery:find input field closest to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357017/jquery-find-input-field-closest-to-button)

[Understand javascripts 'this' with clarity](https://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

[Finding Closest p tag to the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369606/finding-closest-p-to-the-clicked-button)

I have look at more places, thought I would just show those I found most informing. What do I need to do here and to what `$(this)` is referring within the function?

Comment: `fileupload` isn't a `jquery` event as far as I know.. You are using any library?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I use the Jquery file upload library, i will change it to not confuse what the question is about

Comment: $(this) represent your button or your current obj

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611233/jquery-this-selector-function-and-limitations

Comment: You code has a syntax error! You can't use a statement in object literals! You need to use a callback function.

Comment: @NegiRox, thank you. So would I be correct to assume that $(this).closest(span.fileError) would refer to the closest element with that class

Comment: probably yes. if no other div having same content before

Comment: @undefined please review the question it is not regarding my syntax but rather which element $(this) refers to within a function. NegiRox  and Jamiec have helped me understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it referring to the button element or is it referring to the function itself.

In jQuery event handler functions, `this` refers to the DOM element itself, and `$(this)` wraps that in a jQuery object.

But the real answer to your question of how to change the HTML of your span is going to depend on what `fileupload` is.

Comment: fileupload is a function that runs my upload ajax when the file input is clicked. so in this case any errors that are returned should be written to that span. I hope this provides some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of function will you use as event handler:

- arrow function takes this from the outer scope
- normal function has `this` assigned to a current element when used as an event handler.

```js
$('.understanding-arrow').click(() => {
  console.log(this === window && "this is window");

  $(this).closest('div').find('span.fileError').html('My brain needs help');
});
$('.understanding-normal').click(function() {
  console.log(this === $('.understanding-normal')[0] && "this is input el");

  $(this).closest('div').find('span.fileError').html('My brain needs help');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="fileError"></span>
  <input type="button" class="understanding-arrow" value="arrow function" />
</div>
<div>
  <span class="fileError"></span>
  <input type="button" class="understanding-normal" value="normal function" />
</div>
```